# pass parameter to next page with javascript

Tags: javascript

The javascript will auot generate some photo and description of the photo.
I need to click on the photo, and then it will send a parameter(title) to next page, so let next page generate the information base on what photo I click

Here is my code, I try to use document.submit() to do it but it seem fail.

In the first page:

```
function print(){
  var detail = getVideo();
  var number = detail.length;
   document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML = "";
  for (i=0;i<=number;i++){
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<a href="play.html" onclick="submitvideo(detail[i].title)"><img src='+detail[i].poster+'></a>');
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<h class="vname">'+detail[i].title+'</h>')
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<p>'+detail[i].desc+'</p>');
}


function submitvideo(title){
  title.submit();
}
```

In the second page:(now is just use to test can it pass or not)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getv(){
  alert(document.location.search);

}
</script>
```

Comment: use parameter in the redirect link with `www.newlink.com?title=photoTitle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use href as a parameter holder `href="play.html?title='+detail[i].title+'"`

```
function print(){
  var detail = getVideo();
  var number = detail.length;
   document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML = "";
  for (i=0;i<=number;i++){
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<a href="play.html?title='+detail[i].title+'"><img src='+detail[i].poster+'></a>');
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<h class="vname">'+detail[i].title+'</h>')
  document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<p>'+detail[i].desc+'</p>');
}
```

In `play.html` you can split the link and get the `photoTitle`

```
var fullUrl = window.location.href;
var titlePhoto = fullUrl.split("title=")[1];
console.log(titlePhoto)
```

Comment: You can use `location.search` as well

Answer (score 0):

change your code with like this

```
document.getElementById("watch").innerHTML += ('<a href="play.html?title='+detail[i].title+'"><img src='+detail[i].poster+'></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are from the same domain and protocol could [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) help you here?